# Push all zeros to tail of int array

Tags: python

My script pushes zeros to end of an int array. I'd like to be reviewed on efficiency, style, and obviously if there is a bug I would like to know.

```
def nonzero(a):
  ''' given an array of ints, push all zeros to the end '''
  zeros = [0 for i in range(a.count(0))]
  x = [ i for i in a if i != 0]
  x.extend(zeros)
  return(x)
```

Comment: [Related question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23844828/2301450)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. The function does not preserve object identity. Zeros of other types get replaced with an integer:

   ```
   >>> nonzero([0, 0.0, 0j])
   [0, 0, 0]
   ```

   If the input only ever contains integers, then this isn't a problem, but it's worth remembering that Python has several different types of number.
2. The docstring is not quite right. "push all the zeros to the end" implies that the input array is modified, but that's not true: a new array is created and returned.
3. There's a neat trick for implementing this:

   ```
   def nonzero(a):
       """Return a copy of the iterable a with all zeros at the end."""
       return sorted(a, key=lambda x: x == 0)
   ```

   This works because `False` compares less than `True`, and because Python's sort is guaranteed to be stable: it never changes the relative order of elements with the same sort key.

Comment: not before commenting of course. I mixed up "False compares less than True" and thought "False will be at the end", not "False will be at the beginning". My apologies.

Answer (score 5):

`nonzero` is not a great name for this function. It implies a check to see if something is nonzero, not a simple sort method. It is hard to name something like this, but even the overly long `zeroes_to_end` would be clearer as it's not ambiguously implying something else. Likewise `a` and `x` aren't great, instead maybe `source` and `result`? (assuming you don't decide to modify the original list as Gareth Rees suggested)

Also instead of:

```
zeros = [0 for i in range(a.count(0))]
```

It'd be easier to just do this:

```
zeros = [0] * a.count(0)
```

which will give you the same thing.

Lastly you don't need parentheses around your `return` value. You can just do `return a` which reads as more Pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

I'd improve your second comprehension: 
`[i for i in a if i]`.
It's more Pythonic to write `if i` than `if i!=0`

This works because

a) Python makes some implicit type conversions and

b) in Python almost anything can be converted to boolean (e.g. when you type `if some_var:`). You will get `false` if `some_var` is not initialized, if it is `0` (not `'0'`),  empty string, empty collection, etc.

Comment: Hi, nice suggestion! You may want to explain why this works, as the OP may not be familiar with Python's truthiness.

Comment: Good explanation, though I'm not sure if I'm understanding your *"not initialized"* comment. If the name doesn't exist it will generate a `NameError`, unless your Python treats it differently?

Comment: Yes, it does generate Name Error. Not sure why it appeared in my definition of Python truth...

Answer (score 2):

If it is acceptable to work with numpy arrays. I prefer its syntax over lambda functions and list comprehensions.

```
def shift_zeros(a):
    return np.concatenate([a[a != 0], a[a == 0]])
```